# starcluster easy_install windows

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, easy-install, starcluster

I am trying to setup a R cluster on AWS using StarCluster and lateron BioCoductor AMI. The objective is to run some parallel computations on multiple nodes using snow.

However I am already stuck at the beginning in installing StarCluster on WINDOWS 7 64bit (probably the reason).

What did I do:
(http://star.mit.edu/cluster/docs/latest/installation.html)

1. Install Python 2.7.5
2. added the c:\Pyhton\Scripts directory to PATH (and even restarted)
3. installed setuptools 0.6rc11
4. pycrypto 2.3
5. opened a CMD prompt in c:\Python\Scripts and executed: easy_install StarCluster

However it ends with an error. Looks like it is not using the right folders

Has anyone an idea?

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>easy_install StarCluster
Searching for StarCluster
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/StarCluster/
Best match: StarCluster 0.94
Downloading pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/StarCluster/StarCluster-
0.94.tar.gz#md5=982f59fde2a32b4bc059a497f5c0a0b7
Processing StarCluster-0.94.tar.gz
Running StarCluster-0.94\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir 
c:\users\floris\appdata\local\temp\easy_in
stall-6bfhto\StarCluster-0.94\egg-dist-tmp-fb1ysr
Adding starcluster 0.94 to easy-install.pth file
Installing starcluster-script.py script to C:\Python27\Scripts
Installing starcluster.exe script to C:\Python27\Scripts
Installing starcluster.exe.manifest script to C:\Python27\Scripts

Installed c:\python27\lib\site-packages\starcluster-0.94-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for StarCluster
Searching for optcomplete>=1.2-devel
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/optcomplete/
Best match: optcomplete 1.2-devel
Downloading pypi.python.org/packages/source/o/optcomplete/optcomplete-1.2-
devel.tar.gz#md5=6392cd0a7154b3394004d5ad9d913d59
Processing optcomplete-1.2-devel.tar.gz
Running optcomplete-1.2-devel\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir 
c:\users\floris\appdata\local\temp\ea
sy_install-hbgocr\optcomplete-1.2-devel\egg-dist-tmp-ifrkgu
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
No eggs found in c:\users\floris\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-hbgocr\optcomplete-
1.2-devel\egg-dist-tmp-ifrkgu (setup script problem?)
error: Could not find required distribution optcomplete>=1.2-devel
```

Comment: No eggs found in c:\users\floris\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-hbgocr\optcomplete-
1.2-devel\egg-dist-tmp-ifrkgu (setup script problem?) It looks like there is a problem with that package and the easy_install script doesn't go any further.

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with easy_install. This link helped me:

http://star.mit.edu/cluster/mlarchives/1942.html

Basically says to use pip instead of easy_install

> pip install starcluster

I found the pip binaries I needed for the installation here:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pip

Using pip it worked just fine.